# Barcode scanner input into excel

Tags: excel, barcode-scanner

is there a way i could create a simple program/code that allows me to have excel automatically create cell gaps between barcode scanned text the information should be presented as:
Sample number 1
Sample number 1
Gap
Gap
Sample number 2
Sample number 2

I use a barcode scanner (datalogics gryphon) to scan blood samples and work and constantly need to press enter in order to manually create gaps between the blood samples i scan. Is there any way i could have this done automatically. The normal gist is usually "scan, enter, scan, enter, enter, enter, scan" I want to remove the need of pressing enter  between scanning. I need to scan countless blood samples on a day-to-day basis and this will increase speed by a dramatic amount

Comment: Add the VBA tag to your question. I believe the answer is yes, using the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Comment: Do you only want one cell between scans? Your description suggests it's sometimes one cell, sometimes 2 cells.

Comment: Are you on a Mac or are you on a Windows machine?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A bar code reader sends character to an application in the similar way a keyboard way does.
A simple way would be to print on a blank sheet the bar code for "Enter". The enter command is "CR" and the value in hexadecimal is "0D".
Scanning the "CR" code between each sample doesn't remove a step but avoids going to the keyboard.

Comment: is there a way i can make the barcode for enter occur multiple times within the one code?

Comment: The Bar Code created could have multiple "CR", it's only limited by the maximum number of characters your reader can handle.

Answer (score 0):

You could program the barcode scanner to always 'hit' Enter after each scanned barcode.
Below are the barcode codes to be scanned in order to add the suffix 'Enter' for a Datalogic Gryphon GM4100.
Note: In some cases you might need to add 20 sets of 2 characters (in total 40 characters): 0A 00 00 ... 00

[Add 'Enter' Suffix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53ayQ.png)